# injecting service into CanActivate method of router Guard

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

before redirecting to page i am doing simple check using below service

```
  import { Injectable,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    export class UserCheck {
    private userState:boolean = false;
        get isValid(): boolean{
            return this.userState;
        }
        set isValid(usrstate){
        this.userState = usrstate;
        }  
    }
```

User check is service that set `isValid` to true or false in another service;
Assume that another service has set `isValid` to true, I am using providers to have sigle instance of `UserCheck` of usercheck service. But when guard actually get executed its not considering value that was set to true.

```
    import { CanActivate,ActivatedRouteSnapshot,RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
    import { UserCheck } from './UserCheck' ;
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

    @Injectable()
    export class UserDetailGuard implements CanActivate{            
        constructor (private usrstate:UserCheck){ 
            console.log ("guard in action " + this.usrstate.isValid) }
        canActivate(route:ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state:RouterStateSnapshot) : Observable<boolean> | boolean{
            console.log ("guard executed.. " + this.usrstate.isValid)
                return this.usrstate.isValid;
        }
    }
```

As soon as page load value of `this.usrstate.isValid` can be seen to true in console log `guard in action true` in constructor code (see image), but when i actually navigate to page it does not consider value of `this.usrstate.isValid` and assign default value which is false.

[image]

**app.module.js**
Removed unnecessary code..

```
      import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
  import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
  import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
  import { FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
  import { routing } from './app.rotes';
  import { UserCheck } from './UserCheck';
  import { LogMessage } from './LogMessage';
  import { AccessDenied } from './AccessDenied';
  import { UserDetailGuard } from './UserDetailGuard'

  @NgModule({
    imports:      [ BrowserModule,FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule,routing,],
    declarations: [ AppComponent,AccessDenied ],
    bootstrap:    [ AppComponent],
    providers: [UserCheck,LogMessage,UserDetailGuard]
  })
  export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Your UserDetailGuard class and UserCheck service should be placed in the same NgModule (because guard has to use proper instance). Could you show your module code?

Comment: @ Kamil Myśliwiec added module.js code